# Is there a way to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without the software, just command line?

Tags: 14.04

Is there a way to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without the software, just command line? (desktop version, ***not server***)

Thank you.

Comment: User  user68186: sorry I was unclear, but what I want is just an OS, with no additional software, not even a desktop. I want to see a command prompt when I boot, nothing else. I want to build the system from the ground up. But I want the desktop version (without the desktop), not the server.

Comment: Then you want the [Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

Comment: Sounds good... thanks. What about 'Ubuntu Core'?

Comment: Snappy Ubuntu Core is targeted at servers, embedded SoC, Raspberry Pi and clouds, so you need the Ubuntu Minimal CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server version is what you want. It only differs from the desktop version in that it *does not* install any package related to desktop. Other than that, it is the same, apart from the kernel, which is tailored to server duties. From that point, you can add whatever package you need, so you can build your own system.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. So, the server version is the same as the desktop version, just no desktop or applications? I'm just trying to be clear...

Comment: Yes, you can see this when you look at the package URLs in /etc/apt/sources.list. They are the same for server and desktop ergo both use the same packages, but a different choice of pre-selected packages.